# Should my dog be able to clean out an appropriately sized Kong?

Tags: dogs, treats

We have a Kong classic for our 1 year-old dog. She loves the Kong and spends plenty of time with it, but there always ends up being about half of an inch of peanut butter stuck at the very bottom of the interior.

Does this mean that the Kong is too small for her tongue? Should she be able to clean out thoroughly an appropriately sized Kong, given enough time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have multiple size kongs and it seems to us its really down to your dog and its ability to "get in there". We have a 50kg American Bull/Rotty/Shep and a Rotty/Staffie (25kg) and the bigger dog has a smaller tongue than the other one, but he can clean out any of the Kongs, the little one struggles or is less experienced at it

The largest size they do (XXL?) is huge and has a big opening, i would recommend going for those, if they cant clean it out, you can pick it up after and easily push the stuff out for them once they discarded it... plus they easier to clean. I also agree to put dry on the bottom as mentioned by Shirru

On a side note, the large dog destroys ANY toy in minutes or seconds, our Kongs are years old and still in good shape

Answer (score 1):

If you have appropriate size buying bigger kong would make it much easier to lick first layers of filling, If you want to avoid leftover filling on bottom, you can put dry food or dog cookies first and then close kong with peanut butter or wet food. Sometimes even with dry filling my puppy doesn't eat everything that is inside.

But what breed is you dog and what size of kong do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This is why we stopped putting peanut butter into Kongs.

What we do (in the warmer months) is put some kibble into a bowl and pour over some hot water.  After it's soaked for a while, we load the paste into Kongs and put them in the freezer.

The next day, the dog has the Kong and can happily spend half an hour or so licking at it and gradually melting the paste.  Invariably the Kongs come back mostly clean.

The other plus point is that it takes a long time to eat, the dog is actively engaged, and doesn't get frustrated because there's always a (small amount of) reward.

As a side note, we take this kibble out of the dog's daily allowance, so we're not in danger of over-feeding whenever there's treats on offer.